# What kind of car do I have?

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, word-property

What kind of car do I have?
The clue words:
stories, robbery, rock, minimum, old, ducks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you have a

> Tesla

Reasoning

> The clue words **stories, robbery, rock, minimum, old, ducks** correspond to the words **tales, steal, slate, least, stale** and **teals**, respectively, all of which are anagrams of **tesla** (the type of car).